# How to tokenize an String like in lexer in java?

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, search, split

Lines of code which i want to tokenize according to lexer rules.

```
  String input1 = input.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");

     List<String> uncleanList = Arrays.asList(input1.split(" "));
```

I put this code in String.
replaced all multi spaces into one space

```
String s = codeString.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

then

```
  String t= s.split(" ")
```

method on that string which gave me an array with the help of single space.
i got this Array result(This is console output by System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)); ):

```
[String, input1, =, input.replaceAll("\\s+",", ");, List<String>, uncleanList, =, Arrays.asList(input1.split(", "));]
```

but there are alot of ( ) brackets, <> , . dots "" etc without space separation. Now i am stuck here . How to separate symbols from alphabets or numbers on separate index .

Desired Array output when print Array on console:

```
 [String, input1, =, input,.,replaceAll,(,"\\s+"," ",),;, List,<,String,>, uncleanList, =, Arrays,.,asList,(,input1,.,split,(," ",),),;,]
```

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail to be answered adequately. Can you also include in your question, a sample string that contains the tokens you want to separate, and also include what the result should be once the string is tokenized

Comment: You can see the java code in my question which i need to tokenize

Comment: When you are ready to properly ask your question, refer to the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Finally your last code examples with the [ text in square brackets ], that isn't Java syntax. So please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @MattTimmermans it is getting there now. The initial attempt with that "do not downvote if you don't know the answer", that was not at all okay. If you want to help the OP, rather edit the question and throw out such stuff!

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have a delimiter to use, `split` stops being an effective way to do tokenization.  Instead of using split to find the parts you don't want, use `find` to find the parts you do want, like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+|[+-]?[0-9\\._Ee]+|\\S");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) {
  String token = matcher.group();
}
```

The example regex I provide here is simpler that what you really want.  The important thing is that you provide the default pattern (\S) to match any non-whitespace character that isn't included in a longer match.  That will take care of all the single-character tokens.

Some of the longer tokens you have to match, like strings and comments, are pretty complicated, so it will take some work to get this right.

Comment: can you transform your answer as my desired output.