# How to put Java Regex matches to Resultant String?

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm

[How to tokenize an String like in lexer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920961/how-to-tokenize-an-string-like-in-lexer-in-java)

Please refer to the above question. I never used java regex . How to put the all substring into new string  with matched characters (symbols like '(' ')' '.' '<' '>' ") separated by single space . for e.g. before regex

```
 String c= "List<String> uncleanList = Arrays.asList(input1.split("x"));" ;
```

I want resultant string like this  .

```
String r= " List < String > uncleanList = Arrays . asList ( input1 . split ( " x " ) ) ; "
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the code that you linked to, `matcher.group()` will give you a single token. Simple use a StringBuilder to append this token and a space to get a new string where the tokens are space-separated.

```
String c = "List<String> uncleanList = Arrays.asList(input1.split(\"x\"));" ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+|[+-]?[0-9\\._Ee]+|\\S");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(c);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String token = matcher.group();
    sb.append(token).append(" ");
}
String r = sb.toString();
System.out.println(r);
```

Comment: code is working fine... but my follow up question is : if i need to ignore symbols between " " or ' ' or  [] . so How can i do this? please answer + refer me some useful tutorial according to my problem.

Comment: That’s basically a manual version of `String r = pattern.matcher(c).replaceAll("$0 ");` You could even do the replacement ad-hoc, calling `replaceAll` directly on the input string, like `System.out.println(c.replaceAll("\\w+|[+-]?[0-9\\._Ee]+|\\S", "$0 "));`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String c = "List<String> uncleanList = Arrays.asList(input1.split('x'));";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\.|\\(|\\)").matcher(c);

    while(matcher.find()){
        String symbol = matcher.group();
        c = c.replace(symbol," " + symbol + " ");
    }
```

Actually if you look deeply You can figure out that you have to separate only not alphabet symbols and space ((?![a-zA-Z]|\ ).)

Comment: input string contains "x" not 'x'.

Comment: Have you checked how it works? it works fine, I wrote ' because I would not want to write \"